# PyTorch RuntimeError: "nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d_index" not implemented for 'Int'

Tags: python, pytorch

Trying to implement a TGCN model on my local machine ([entire code link](https://github.com/dxli94/WLASL)) and I get this above Runtime error related to PyTorch. This issue doesn't happen when I implement the same code on Google Colab. What's the issue here and how do I fix it? Thanks

Here's the traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\signlanguage\code\TGCN\train_tgcn.py", line 123, in <module>
    run(split_file=split_file, configs=configs, pose_data_root=pose_data_root)
  File "C:\signlanguage\code\TGCN\train_tgcn.py", line 64, in run
    train_losses, train_scores, train_gts, train_preds = train(log_interval, model,
  File "C:\signlanguage\code\TGCN\train_utils.py", line 27, in train
    loss = compute_loss(out, y)
  File "C:\signlanguage\code\TGCN\train_utils.py", line 146, in compute_loss
    ce_loss = F.cross_entropy(out, gt)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 3026, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
RuntimeError: "nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d_index" not implemented for 'Int'
```

Snippet of train_utils.py file code:

```
 def train(log_interval, model, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
        # set model as training mode
        losses = []
        scores = []
        train_labels = []
        train_preds = []
    
        N_count = 0  # counting total trained sample in one epoch
        for batch_idx, data in enumerate(train_loader):
            X, y, video_ids = data
            # distribute data to device
            X, y = X.cuda(), y.cuda().view(-1, )
    
            N_count += X.size(0)
    
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            out = model(X)  # output has dim = (batch, number of classes)
    
            loss = compute_loss(out, y)
    
            # loss = F.cross_entropy(output, y)
            losses.append(loss.item())
    
            # to compute accuracy
            y_pred = torch.max(out, 1)[1]  # y_pred != output
    
            step_score = accuracy_score(y.cpu().data.squeeze().numpy(), y_pred.cpu().data.squeeze().numpy())
    
 

       # collect prediction labels
        train_labels.extend(y.cpu().data.squeeze().tolist())
        train_preds.extend(y_pred.cpu().data.squeeze().tolist())

        scores.append(step_score)  # computed on CPU

        loss.backward()

        # torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=6)
        #
        # for p in model.parameters():
        #     param_norm = p.grad.data.norm(2)
        #     total_norm += param_norm.item() ** 2
        # total_norm = total_norm ** (1. / 2)
        #
        # print(total_norm)

        optimizer.step()

        # show information
        if (batch_idx + 1) % log_interval == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}, Accu: {:.6f}%'.format(
                epoch + 1, N_count, len(train_loader.dataset), 100. * (batch_idx + 1) / len(train_loader), loss.item(),
                100 * step_score))

    return losses, scores, train_labels, train_preds

def compute_loss(out, gt):
ce_loss = F.cross_entropy(out, gt)

return ce_loss
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that both your objects have the same type when you call `F.cross_entropy()`. You probably have two different type on this line `loss = compute_loss(out, y)`, where `y` is either `float` or `long` type tensor and `out` is `int`.

You have to cast your `out` to the same type as `y` with something like this

```
out.type(torch.LongTensor)
```

or this for `float`

```
out.type(torch.FloatTensor)
```

Hope this helps.